# Customizing Scroll Wheel Zooming in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can you customize the scroll wheel zooming in Google Maps? If a user uses the scroll wheel on their mouse, I want the map to zoom by 2 or 3 levels. Is it possible?

Check out my jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jj7ymt5c/1/

I get the following error in the console: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Here's the code:

```
function initializeMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.35210605281608, -83.12983274459839),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may disable the built-in scrollwheel-zooming and implement your own handler:

```js
function initializeMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 14,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.35210605281608, -83.12983274459839),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }),
    fx = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var z = (e.wheelDelta > 0 || e.detail < 0) ? 3 : -3;
      map.setZoom(Math.max(0, Math.min(22, map.getZoom() + z)));
      return false;
    };
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mousewheel', fx);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'DOMMouseScroll', fx);
  
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

---

The fix related to the comments(zoom to mouse-position):

the relevant part is the `projection_changed`-handler, add it somewhere after the creation of the `google.maps.Map`-instance

---

```js
function initializeMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 7,
      scrollwheel:false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.352, -83.129)
    });
  
  
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'projection_changed',function(){
      
      var steps=3,//the desired zoom-steps on each mousescroll 
          goo = google.maps,
          map = this,
          div = map.getDiv();
      goo.event.addListener(map,'scrollwheel_changed',function(){
      
      var evs = this.get('wheelevents');
      if(this.get('scrollwheel')){
         if(evs){
            for(var k in evs){
              goo.event.removeListener(evs[k])
            }
         }
         this.set('wheelevents',{})
      }
      else{
         var fx = function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var target  = e.target || e.srcElement;
              
              if(target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode!==div){
                return;
              }        
              
              var rect    = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
                  dir     = ((e.wheelDelta > 0 || e.detail < 0) ? 1 : -1)*steps,
                  zoom    = Math.max(0, Math.min(25, map.getZoom() + dir)),
                  fz      = Math.pow(2,map.getZoom()),
                  mo      = { x:  e.clientX - rect.left,
                              y:  e.clientY - rect.top},
                  co      = { x:  div.offsetWidth/2,
                              y:  div.offsetHeight/2},
                  cp  = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getCenter()),
                  mc  = map.getProjection()
                             .fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(
                             (cp.x*fz-(target.offsetWidth/2-mo.x))/fz
                             ,
                             (cp.y*fz-(target.offsetHeight/2-mo.y))/fz
                             )),
                  mp= map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(mc),
                  __zoom,__fz,__cp;
              
              map.setZoom(zoom);
              __zoom=map.getZoom();
              __fz=Math.pow(2,__zoom)
              __cp=new google.maps.Point(
                (mp.x+(co.x-mo.x)/__fz)
                ,
                (mp.y+(co.y-mo.y)/__fz)
              );
              map.setCenter(map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(__cp))
              return false;
            };
            
         this.set('wheelevents',
                  {
                    mousewheel: goo.event.addDomListener(div, 
                                                        'mousewheel', fx),
                    mousescroll:goo.event.addDomListener(div, 
                                                        'DOMMouseScroll', fx)
                  }
                 );
      }
    });
    goo.event.trigger(map,'scrollwheel_changed')
  });  

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

---

**Note:** This will observe the `scrollwheel`-property of the map, to apply the desired behaviour from the beginning set the `scrollwheel`-option of the map to `false`. When you want to add/remove the behaviour later set the scrollwheel-property via `set`:

```
map.set('scrollwheel',true);//or false
```

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that it zooms to the center of the map. Is there a way to zoom to where the mouse cursor is?

Comment: Any thoughts? Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I have to work this weekend, but I promise I will try to solve it as soon as possible(of course  it's possible, when the API may do it, it's possible)

Answer (score 2):

So there are 2 problems,

1) current zoom level+2 can exceed 20, which is the maximum zoom level google maps support. You should make sure it does not go over 20.

2) set zoom would actually trigger your on zoom change listener. So you should put a flag or something, to indicate if this zoom is trigger by user or by set zoom level

Answer (score 1):

You might be exceeding the zoom size Range.
Therefore,

- 1.First, please know the zoom range available by **mapObject.getZoom()**
        and then
- 2.Use if condition to increment setZoom() by 2 only if the current zoom  size is below the range by 2.

For example, the zoom range available for your zone is 0-20,
then use if condition to check the current zoom size if not >18 then set zoom size = current zoom size +2
which would reach upto max 20....

```
if (map.getZoom() < 19) 
{
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow is due to the behavior of the recursive function you created.
As a normal mousewheel action is triggered, zoom is triggered, your code is running, and changes the zoom, and since this changes the zoom, your code runs again and again and again.
The answers provided by others do the job. But to have zoom at mouse point, you need to pan your map first to put the position of the mouse at the center of the div area.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted like an lot of time on this and all the code that was supplied is correct but also un necessary as mouse scroll is false by default and you need to use ctrl + scroll wheel that tells me the function is already there and no need to create the function like all the answers supplied it is very, very simple:

```
 function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
        zoom: 2,
        scrollwheel: true,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
```

Ass scrollwheel zoom is false by default in the function supplied by google insert
scrollwheel: true,
and zoom level 2
no need for hours of coding!.